# Error when trying to link to a shared library I created using LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c++, linux, malloc, shared-libraries

I'm trying to test if I can override the glibc's malloc interface by linking a shared library on Linux. I don't have the details for the malloc functions yet.

So I created a `nullmalloc.cpp` that has the required replacements for malloc, but all returns null. The code looks like this:

```
# include <cstddef>

void* malloc(size_t size) { return 0; }
void* calloc(size_t n, size_t size) { return 0; }
void free(void* ptr) { return; }
void* realloc(void* ptr, size_t size) { return 0; }
void* valloc(size_t size) { return 0; }
void* memalign(size_t align, size_t s) { return 0; }
void cfree(void* ptr) { return; }
void* aligned_alloc(size_t align, size_t s) { return 0; }
void* pvalloc(size_t size) { return 0; }
struct mallinfo mallinfo(void);
int mallopt(int cmd, int value) { return 0; }
```

And then I tried to make a shared library of the cpp file by these commands:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -g -c nullmalloc.cpp // creates nullmalloc.o
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,nullmalloc.so -o nullmalloc.so nullmalloc.o // creates nullmalloc.so
```

When I used LD_PRELOAD to link `nullmalloc.so` to a test code I wrote called `test.cpp`, I got an error saying that the .so file could not be found.

The command I used with LD_PRELOAD is this:

```
g++ -g test.cpp -o test.o -std=c++11 LD_PRELOAD=/home/nullmalloc/nullmalloc.so
```

And the error I got is this:

```
g++: error: LD_PRELOAD=/home/nullmalloc/nullmalloc.so: No such file or directory
```

I'm confused because the `nullmalloc.so` file exists when I use the `ls` command.

```
[root@a nullmalloc]$ ls
nullmalloc.cpp  nullmalloc.o  nullmalloc.so  test.cpp
```

I've only started studying about malloc, linux, and shared libraries, so I'm not sure where I've made a mistake. Could anyone give advice on where to start fixing?

Thank you.

Comment: Use  [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) on the ELF executable you are using to test your library

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Right now I can't create an executable because the library can't be found :( The error occurs when I'm trying to create an executable of test.cpp with LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: Use [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) and [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) on the process running your library. Read Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf). See also [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html), [objdump(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) and [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)

Comment: You're passing LD_PRELOAD=/home/... as a command line arg to `g++` -- that won't work.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @G.M. I'm trying to make an executable that is linked to the shared library I made. Though I'm not sure if I correctly created a shared library...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you for the resources! Right now there doesn't seem to be a process running the library? And I am going to read the paper but did I incorrectly create the shared library? (The filename ends in .so but isn't a real shared library)

Comment: typo: you must fix "void cfree(void* ptr) { return 0; }" return nothing or change function prototype.

Comment: @PicaudVincent Fixed! Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how to add compiler flag, but you can make it works as follows.

Compile test as usual:

```
g++ -Wall -g test.cpp -o test -std=c++11
```

Invoke it like this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/home/nullmalloc/nullmalloc.so ./test
```

Comment: Yes @BasileStarynkevitch One must always use -Wall... Only truly paranoids survive, as JP B. says :)

Comment: Actually use `g++ -Wall -Wextra`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch as I also do most of the time... However I must confess that I never used `-pedantic`... That's too much :-)

Comment: Thank you! Now the LD_PRELOAD option works :) The library doesn't seem to link though... I'm guessing it might be a problem with my malloc alternatives.